# Removing Component in Gridlayout Leaves Empty Spaces

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, flowlayout

Very similar if not exactly the same question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727728/invisible-components-still-take-up-space-jpanel).
I simply remove a JButton from the middle of a row of JButtons and it dissapears but still takes up space! The answer in the attached thread doesn't suit my case, hence not useful to me who doesn't know how to create that new layout.
I also tried a flolayout, but the exact same happens.

**EDIT**

revalidating and repainting worked.

Comment: Call `revalidate`, followed by `repaint` on the container you've removed the button from

Comment: I will check and reply tomorrow, I hope it's that easy.

Comment: JList sounds like a great tool! thanks Andrew

Comment: Tried JList<JButton>, didn't change much at all..