# How to render JTableHeader when using headless mode?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I'm trying to render a png image from JTable and using headless mode. JTable's main area is rendered. But JTableHeader area can't rendered.And when I call JTableHeader#getPreferedSize(), JVM is crashed by getting theme for rendering.

Has anyone resolved this issue?

Comment: Try the suggestions on [Why does the JTable header not appear in the image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369814/why-does-the-jtable-header-not-appear-in-the-image)

Comment: I got it! I set Look and Feel to UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName(). Then the issue is solved!

Comment: Thank you,Andrew. Your suggestion is what I needed. The link set Look And Feel to Nimbas. I have to set it!