# JScrollPane and printAll()

Tags: java, swing, paint

I am working on a JPanel extension that is only for rendering its contents to a BufferedImage, which I then use as a texture for rendering in OpenGL. For this, I create my special JPanel extension with a layout manager etc., like I would if I was building a normal Swing GUI.

In order to render it to an image, I make sure to call `doLayout` first and then I use the `printAll(java.awt.Graphics)` method to print it and the added components:

```
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
    printAll(g);
```

Swing itself (EDT, RepaintManager etc) is never involved, I just create the components (outside any window or frame) and directly use printAll.

This is working perfectly well for most "atomic" components (such as buttons, labels, lists), but I hit on a problem with the JScrollPane. Whatever I try, the JScrollPane will never paint its viewports (the main viewport and the scroll bars) to the given Graphics but only its border, and even manually calling `printAll` on the viewports yields no result.

I attached two screenshots which show a "before and after" of a simple GUI consisting of a JList and a JButton. On the first image, I use the raw JList, in the second image, I wrapped it into a JScrollPane using `new JScrollPane(list)`.

[image: Using a JList directly]
[image: Using a JList wrapped in a JScrollPane]

I failed to find any magic inside the JScrollPane code related to painting its viewports. Maybe something needs to be initialized that Swing would do, but I forgot. Is there any way I can get those viewports to show up?

Comment: Using `validate()` (which needs, in my case, a call to `addNotify()` first) instead of `doLayout()` fixes the problem, thanks!

Comment: Any chance you could make that comment an answer so I can accept it? I'm not sure how to proceed here on StackOverflow if the actual answer is kinda "hidden" in another question's answer and has been hinted using a comment...

Comment: Umm.. apparently not.  I just tried that, only to see a new comment with addendum **Trivial answer converted to comment**  ;)  I'll try again, something a little more subtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Why does the JTable header not appear in the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7369814/418556) for some general tips about rendering components to images.  Try calling combinations of `validate()`, `addNotify()` & `doLayout()` as mentioned in the code of that thread.

Answer (score 1):

not sure from your question

1) if there is about `JScrollPane` or `JViewport`, becasue `JViewport` is only (from `JScrollPane`) about visible `Rectangle` on the screen,

2) every `JComponent` returns `Graphics2D`

3) please why do you call `doLayout()` / `addNotify()`, in the case that all events for Swing GUI are done on EDT, or are there some events based on `Swing Timer`

4) better would be edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that generated un_wanted output to the GUI

5) for `JViewport` you have to create and override your own `RepaintManager`

6) maybe stupid question, please ensure us that there isn't any animations of JComponent, meaning moving accross `JScrollPane` and freezed on EDT by `Thread.sleep(int)`

EDIT (could be most important)

7) for `OpenGL` you have to implements `Components` based on `Java AWT`

Comment: I am not sure which of those things do not get clear in my question.
I am only just rendering components using their `printAll` methods, there is no EDT (unless the instantiation of a JComponent creates one), there are no events which could be dispatched and I do not use any timers. The _SSCCE_ is just there, do a `printAll` on a component that has not been added to any kind of an actual window (e.g. JFrame) and thus is not managed by Swing's 100s of managers, and you should get a very similar result.

Comment: @pdinklag there are common areas 1) JComponents, 2) LayoutManager, 3) Graphics2D, 4) working with Graphics2D, 5) printing modified or broken Graphics2D, baterry not included :-)