# How to save a scrollable JPanel as a jpeg image (not as a snapshot)

Tags: java, swing, awt, jpanel

How is it possible to store a `JPanel` as a *jpeg* image the solutions I could search takes a snapshot of the display, this does not capture all the contents of the `JPanel` as part of it is hidden. Is there any way of getting the entire image in *jpeg*.

This solution available here is not working fine at all  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272938/how-to-save-panel-as-image-in-swing)

code I am currently using to take snapshot of JPanel

```
if (panelx == null) {
            jButton3.setText("Generate Diagram");
        } else {
            jButton3.setText("Generate Diagram");
            jTextPane1
                    .setText(Messages.getString("statement2")); //$NON-NLS-1$
            JFrame win = (JFrame) SwingUtilities
                    .getWindowAncestor(panelx.panelx);
            Dimension size = win.getSize();
            // BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height,
            // BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) win.createImage(size.width,
                    size.height);
            Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
            win.paint(g);
            g.dispose();
            try {

                ImageIO.write(
                        image,
                        Messages.getString("Statement38"), new File(Messages.getString("statement5"))); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Image cannot be created");
            }
```

Comment: Graphics from whole JPanel or only from visible JViewport from JScrollPane

Comment: @mKorbel from the whole JPanel. In order to see the entire image we have to scroll the JPanel. I want a solutiom where we can store this image as jpeg no scroll needed and entire output is there.

Comment: what did you try so far? Or in other words: show an SSCCE that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @kleopatra let me show you the method I am using

Comment: that's not an SSCCE (Google is your friend :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't explain why the example doesn't work.

Why are you using the window not the panel? If you were using the example answer you should refer to the panel within the scrollpane.

You're calling paint on the whole JFrame rather than just the panel you are interested in.