# How to export a complete JTable component in pdf at a specific coordinate

Tags: java, swing, pdf, jtable, itext

In my project I have to print JTable components in a pdf with all the customizations(like borders,colors etc). For this requirement I searched a little bit and found one code to print JTable in pdfs. But after printing I found that table's border for 1st row and 1st columns are missing plus I didn't find a way to print at some specific coordinate. Please look at the specific code below:-

```
package com.jpmorgan.dqreport;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.PageSize;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class JTable2Pdf extends JFrame {
  private JTable table;

  public JTable2Pdf() {
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    createTable();
  }
  private void createTable() {
      Object[][] data = {
                {"Kathy", "Smith",
                 "SnowboardingXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
                {"John", "Doe",
                 "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Sue", "Black",
                 "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
                {"Jane", "White",
                 "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
                {"Joe", "Brown",
                 "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
                };
      String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
              "Last Name",
              "Sport",
              "# of Years",
              "Vegetarian"};

    table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

    JPanel tPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    tPanel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    tPanel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    getContentPane().add(tPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
  private void print() {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    try {
      PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\jTable.pdf"));

      document.open();
      PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

      cb.saveState();
      Graphics2D g2 = cb.createGraphics(500, 500);

      Shape oldClip = g2.getClip();
      g2.clipRect(10, 0, 500, 500);

      table.print(g2);
      g2.setClip(oldClip);

      g2.dispose();
      cb.restoreState();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    document.close();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JTable2Pdf frame = new JTable2Pdf();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.print();
  }
}
```

Please suggest someway to print the entire JTable at a specific coordinate.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I resolved the code by adding like below:-

```
cb.saveState();

PdfTemplate pdfTemplate = cb.createTemplate(table.getWidth(), table.getHeight());
Graphics2D g2 = pdfTemplate.createGraphics(table.getWidth(), table.getHeight());
/*g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g2.drawRect(x-2, y-2, table.getWidth()+2, table.getHeight()+2);*/
table.print(g2);
System.out.println("x="+x + "," + "y=" + y);
cb.addTemplate(pdfTemplate, x, y);
g2.dispose();
cb.restoreState();
```

Answer (score 6):

A `JTable` is notoriously difficult to get rendered correctly for images (or I guess, printing).  See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369814/why-does-the-jtable-header-not-appear-in-the-image) on which some of the gurus weigh in with tips.

Looking closely at the screenshots of that thread suggests that the default Metal table has no border on the far left.

[image]

The table in Nimbus PLAF does, though.

[image]