# Printing multiple components

Tags: java, swing, printing, jpanel, awt

I am trying to send a JTable and a JPanel to the printer in a single print job like this :

```
            PrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            attr.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);

            MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("Page {0}");
            Printable p1 = table.getPrintable(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, null);

            PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();                

            Printable p2 = new ComponentPrinter().returnIt(jPanel1);

            Book book = new Book();
            book.append(p1, pf);
            book.append(p2, pf);

            PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

            pj.setPageable(book);

            if (pj.printDialog(attr)){
                try {
                    pj.print(attr);
                } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                    Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
                }
            }
```

My problem is, this only prints the first Printable added to the Book ; in this case, the JTable. If I swap the order and add the panel first, then it only prints the panel. Can someone point out the error ?

Comment: Any help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10251531/230513)?

Comment: Sadly, no. It´s pretty much the same thing I did. It did give me the idea of trying the printDialog() and print() methods instead of the ones with parameters. The printer dialog then show 2 pages to print, but only prints one. I tried printing ONLY the second page, but then the print job gets stuck.

Comment: The answer is [here][here] [here]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775753/printing-multiple-jtables-as-one-job-book-object-only-prints-1st-table?rq=1

Comment: Now, how do i go about closing this question ?

Comment: No, it wasn´t the PageFormat, I tried that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775753/printing-multiple-jtables-as-one-job-book-object-only-prints-1st-table?rq=1).

The Book passes wrong pageIndex to the added Printables. For more information and a solution click on the link.