# Fitting a JTable in an iText PDF Document

Tags: java, swing, pdf, jtable, itextpdf

I have a `JTable` that has four columns. I am using iText libraries to print PDF documents with data from the JTable. The problem is that the JTable is not showing properly in the PDF. I have searched on Google and came across [the same situation here](http://tiku.io/questions/4204622/create-pdf-file-from-jtable-in-java). The code is similar to mine as well as the output. I have also tried [this example using Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785264/how-to-export-a-complete-jtable-component-in-pdf-at-a-specific-coordinate), however, the result is not changing.

How do we solve this? Please assist. If the codes are necessary, i will post but they are too many classes -i am working on a big application. **The concept I would want is to make the JTable fit on the document.**

Comment: *I am using iTex libraries* - do you actually mean **iText**? Or is there some other library, maybe in the context of TeX, you refer to?

Comment: @mkl thanks I missed **t**, let me put it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long struggle, I managed to make it as shown below. In case someone encounters this, here is the idea that saved me:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        try {
            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("table.pdf"));
            doc.open();
            PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(table.getColumnCount());
            //adding table headers
            for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                pdfTable.addCell(table.getColumnName(i));
            }
            //extracting data from the JTable and inserting it to PdfPTable
            for (int rows = 0; rows < table.getRowCount() - 1; rows++) {
                for (int cols = 0; cols < table.getColumnCount(); cols++) {
                    pdfTable.addCell(table.getModel().getValueAt(rows, cols).toString());

                }
            }
            doc.add(pdfTable);
            doc.close();
            System.out.println("done");
        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: I tried your code. I got one problem and fixed it by using table.getRowCount() instead of table.getRowCount()-1 .

Comment: @Junaid Okay, that is nice. I wrote that code when things could not come out the way I wanted. It was hard and I was a Java junior :)-