# convert my jTable on a pdf document

Tags: java, swing, pdf, jtable, itext

I'm trying to convert a `JTable` on a PDF document using the `iText` library, looking for a solution I found this question which solves my problem: [1] [Fitting a JTable in an iText PDF Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448377/fitting-a-jtable-in-an-itext-pdf-document/46406532#46406532).

Although I have a problem in this line:

```
PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(table.getColumnCount());
```

When I try to create my `PdfTable` it tells me that:

```
pdfTable cannot be applied to given tipes
```

and I dont know the reason why.

Comment: We don't know either... Since 1) You posted no code (a [mcve]), 2) You're not saying which version of `iText` you're using (5 or 7?) They differ from each other. And since we don't know any of them, we can't help you. Please [edit] your question to add those details into it. You may also want to [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42538618/2180785)

Comment: The question is riddled with errors. `PdfPTable` is an iText 5 class, but it's very different from `PdfTable`. **You should never use `PdfTable` since that class is for internal use only.** Actually, the fact that `PdfTable` is mentioned tells me that you're using on old version of iText. You really should upgrade. Also, I can't imagine that iText would throw an error with the typo `tipes`. Finally, you say you found a question that *solves* your problem, but you immediately contradict yourself by saying that a problem occurs (telling us that your problem isn't solved).

Comment: `PdfPTable` excludes iText 7, so it must be iText 5. Maybe iText 2, but that should really be discouraged.