# How to render component that don't exist as part of the visible containment hierarchy

Tags: java, image, swing, awt

How to render JPanel which contains the child components and that don't exist as part of the visible containment hierarchy (i.e. panel has no parent)?

Method `SwingUtilities.paintComponent()` render only panel without the child components.

And how to handle mouse events by this panel?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: See [Why does the JTable header not appear in the image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369814/why-does-the-jtable-header-not-appear-in-the-image) for tips on rendering components without displaying them.

Comment: If you're trying to render the panel to a printer to buffer, you should use `print` or `printAll` instead, but we need some context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Method SwingUtilities.paintComponent() renper only panel without the child components.

- have look at [paintChildren](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html), [paintComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#paintComponents%28java.awt.Graphics%29), depends of code,
- I'd woudn't be to use `paintComponents()` without important reason and good knowledge about [Painting in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)