# How is it possible to give JTable cell border(Left,right,Top,Bottom) of different color?

Tags: java, swing, pdf, jtable, border

We have a requirement to draw a JTable on a pdf. For this requirement I had taken JTable and directly print onto the pdf. But I didn't get the Left and Top borders for a JTable. Plus I have a requirement to cutomize a cell border for a table. 
Is there anyway I can give different color borders to a cell in a JTable?
For eg:-

```
Left Border = Grid Color
Top Border = Grid Color
Right Border = Black Color
Bottom Border =  Grid Color
```

Any suggestions related to this would be very helpful?

Comment: See if [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0okxX.png) is more to spec.  It is a `JTable` rendered using Nimbus PLAF.  For the details, see [Why does the JTable header not appear in the image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369814/why-does-the-jtable-header-not-appear-in-the-image)

Comment: try this with a matte border
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html

Answer (score 8):

The link @andrewthompson provided should give you an answer to the first part of your question of getting the Table's borders to print (a.k.a. [Why does the JTable header not appear in the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369814/why-does-the-jtable-header-not-appear-in-the-image))

To get different color inner borders in the Table (I believe that was your second question), you'll have to use a combination of the `MatteBorder` and `CompoundBorder` in conjunction with a `TableCellRenderer`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;


public class JTableColoredBorder extends Box{

    public JTableColoredBorder(){
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        JTable table = new JTable(5,5);
        table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,0));//Get rid of cell spacing

        //Set your own renderer.  You'll have to set this for Number and Boolean too if you're using those
        CustomRenderer cr = new CustomRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class), Color.red, Color.orange, Color.pink, Color.magenta);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, cr);

        add(table);
    }

    //Custom renderer - do what the natural renderer would do, just add a border
    public static class CustomRenderer implements TableCellRenderer{
        TableCellRenderer render;
        Border b;
        public CustomRenderer(TableCellRenderer r, Color top, Color left,Color bottom, Color right){
            render = r;

            //It looks funky to have a different color on each side - but this is what you asked
            //You can comment out borders if you want too. (example try commenting out top and left borders)
            b = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder();
            b = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(b, BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2,0,0,0,top));
            b = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(b, BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0,2,0,0,left));
            b = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(b, BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0,0,2,0,bottom));
            b = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(b, BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0,0,0,2,right));
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {
            JComponent result = (JComponent)render.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            result.setBorder(b);
            return result;
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new JTableColoredBorder());
        frame.validate();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Add a MatteBorder to the table before you print.

```
Color color = UIManager.getColor("Table.gridColor");
MatteBorder border = new MatteBorder(1, 1, 0, 0, color);
table.setBorder(border);
```

Comment: Upvoted. I think you can set the `Table.gridColor` property through `UIManager` to something you like, along settings border as you have done in your answer, to achieve completely different color.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your code. I really appreciate people who really help us by contributing their time and effort. Well all these solutions will solve the problem. I got a very good resolution on this with the below code:-

```
 package com.swing.data;

import java.awt.*;   
import javax.swing.*;   
import javax.swing.border.*;   
import javax.swing.table.*;   

public class TableExample{   
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("TableExample");   
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
        f.getContentPane().add(createTable());   
        f.pack();   
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){   
            public void run() {   
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);   
                f.setVisible(true);   
            }   
        });   
    }   

    static JComponent createTable() {   
        final JTable table = new JTable(9,9) {   
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;   

            Color B = Color.RED;   
            Color C = this.getGridColor();   
            final Border[][] borders = {   
                {new ZoneBorder(C,B,B,B), new ZoneBorder(B,C,C,C), new ZoneBorder(B,B,C,C)},   
                {new ZoneBorder(C,C,C,B), new ZoneBorder(C,C,C,C), new ZoneBorder(C,B,C,C)},   
                {new ZoneBorder(C,C,B,B), new ZoneBorder(C,C,B,C), new ZoneBorder(C,B,B,C)}   
            };   

            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {   
                Component result = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);   
                if (result instanceof JComponent) {   
                    if(row == 0 && column == 0)
                    ((JComponent) result).setBorder(borders[0][0]);   
                }   
                return result;   
            }   
        };   
        table.setRowHeight(28);   
        //table.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);   
        TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();   
        for(int c = 0; c<table.getColumnCount(); ++c) {   
            TableColumn tc = tcm.getColumn(c);   
            tc.setPreferredWidth(28);   
        }   
        JPanel inner = new JPanel(new GridLayout());   
        //inner.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));   
        inner.add(table);   
        return inner;   
    }   
}  

    package com.swing.data;

import java.awt.*;   
import javax.swing.*;   
import javax.swing.border.*;   

public class ZoneBorder implements Border {   
    private static final int WIDTH = 1;   
    private Color colorN, colorE, colorS, colorW;   

    public ZoneBorder(Color colorN, Color colorE, Color colorS, Color colorW) {   
        this.colorN=colorN;   
        this.colorE=colorE;   
        this.colorS=colorS;   
        this.colorW=colorW;   
    }   

    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {   
        return false;   
    }   

    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {   
        return new Insets(WIDTH,WIDTH,WIDTH,WIDTH);   
    }   

    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {   
        Color old = g.getColor();   
        if (colorN != null) {   
            g.setColor(colorN);   
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, WIDTH);   
        }   
        if (colorE != null) {   
            g.setColor(colorE);   
            g.fillRect(x+width-WIDTH, y, WIDTH, height);   
        }   
        if (colorS != null) {   
            g.setColor(colorS);   
            g.fillRect(x, y+height-WIDTH, width, WIDTH);   
        }   
        if (colorW != null) {   
            g.setColor(colorW);   
            g.fillRect(x, y, WIDTH, height);   
        }   
        g.setColor(old);   
    }   
}
```

Thanks!