# Specifying Side Borders on Individual Cells in JTable

Tags: java, jtable, border, cell, sudoku

I've made a program for entering Sudoku puzzles into a JTable to be saved into a text document. Currently the table is bland and does not have the block sectioning that's present in your general Sudoku puzzle.

How may I go about specifying the cell's border, but only apply it to certain sides, not the entire cell?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12837574/622391) deals with a similar problem, and may be of use to you.