# JTable 1 point border doesn't appear on the grid line

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jtable, itext

I am using

iText version 5.3.3.
Java jdk 1.6.0

I am working on a Report software where user want's to customize JTable cells with 1 point Black border which appears on the JTable as below:-

[image: JTable output]

Pdf Output:

[image: Pdf output]

On both the outputs there is some gap in between the cells for 1 point border cells. We found that lines are not on the grid lines.
Is there anyway possible these border lines come on the grid as 1 point line.
Following is the sample code to test the problem above with JTable and pdfs.

TableImage.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.PageSize;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

class TableImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Hari", new Integer(23), new Double(78.23), (true)},
            {"James", new Integer(23), new Double(47.64), (false)},
            {"Sally", new Integer(22), new Double(84.81), (true)}
        };
        String[] columns = {"Name", "Age", "GPA", "Pass"};
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
        JTableHeader h = table.getTableHeader();
        int x = table.getWidth();
        int y = table.getHeight();
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,
                new ColumnAlignmentRenderer(
                table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)));
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(x, y, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        table.paint(g2);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
        print(table);
    }

    private static void print(JTable table) {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        try {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                    new FileOutputStream("F://jTable.pdf"));
            document.open();
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
            cb.saveState();
            PdfTemplate pdfTemplate = cb.createTemplate(
                    table.getWidth(), table.getHeight());
            Graphics2D g2 = pdfTemplate.createGraphics(
                    table.getWidth(), table.getHeight());
            table.print(g2);
            cb.addTemplate(pdfTemplate, 20, 100);
            g2.dispose();
            cb.restoreState();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        document.close();
    }

    private TableImage() {
    }
}
```

ColumnAlignmentRenderer.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class ColumnAlignmentRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private TableCellRenderer mWrappedRenderer;
    private HashMap objFormatCellMap;

    public ColumnAlignmentRenderer(TableCellRenderer pWrappedRenderer) {
        mWrappedRenderer = pWrappedRenderer;
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable pTable,
            Object pValue, boolean pIsSelected,
            boolean pHasFocus, int pRow, int pColumn) {
        int hAlignment = SwingConstants.LEFT;
        int vAlignment = SwingConstants.CENTER;
        String pattern = "##000.0";
        Font font = pTable.getFont();
        Border cellBorder = pTable.getBorder();
        // Border cellBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder();
        Color backgroundColor = Color.WHITE;
        Color foregroundColor = Color.BLACK;
        // Use the wrapped renderer 
        Component renderedComponent =
                mWrappedRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                pTable, pValue, pIsSelected, pHasFocus, pRow, pColumn);
        int iLeft = 1;
        int iRight = 1;
        int iTop = 1;
        int iBottom = 1;
        Map fontAttributes = font.getAttributes();
        cellBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(cellBorder, 
                new ZoneBorder(iTop, iLeft, iBottom, iRight, Color.BLACK));
        ((JLabel) renderedComponent).setBorder(cellBorder);
        if (pIsSelected) {
            renderedComponent.setBackground(pTable.getSelectionBackground());
        }
        return renderedComponent;
    }

    public void setHashFormatCellData(HashMap hashFormatCellData) {
        this.objFormatCellMap = hashFormatCellData;
    }
}
```

ZoneBorder.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class ZoneBorder implements Border {

    private static final int WIDTH = 1;
    private Color color;
    private int iTop = 0, iRight = 0, iBottom = 0, iLeft = 0;

    public ZoneBorder(int T, int R, int B, int L, Color color) {
        this.iTop = T;
        this.iRight = R;
        this.iBottom = B;
        this.iLeft = L;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return false;
    }

    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(iTop, iRight, iBottom, iLeft);
    }

    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Color oldColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(color);
        for (int i = 0; i < iTop; i++) {
            g.drawLine(x, y + i, x + width - 1, y + i);
        }
        //g.setColor(southColor);
        for (int i = 0; i < iBottom; i++) {
            g.drawLine(x, y + height - i - 1, x + width - 1, y + height - i - 1);
        }
        //g.setColor(eastColor);
        for (int i = 0; i < iLeft; i++) {
            g.drawLine(x + i, y, x + i, y + height - 1);
        }
        //g.setColor(westColor);
        for (int i = 0; i < iRight; i++) {
            g.drawLine(x + width - i - 1, y, x + width - i - 1, y + height - 1);
        }
        g.setColor(oldColor);
    }
}
```

- **Update 1**

I changed the code to decrease intercellspacing of a table cell to 0 with

```
    table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,0));
```

as well as also changed the row margin to 0

```
    table.setRowMargin(0);
```

But when rows are more it shows me blank lines in between the rows at some places as below:-

[image: row spacing image]

For this I increased data to 9 rows with the below code:-

```
 Object[][] data = {
        {"Hari", new Integer(23), new Double(78.23), (true)},
        {"James", new Integer(23), new Double(47.64), (false)},
        {"Sally", new Integer(22), new Double(84.81), (true)},
        {"Sally", new Integer(22), new Double(84.81), (true)},
        {"Sally", new Integer(22), new Double(84.81), (true)},
        {"Hari", new Integer(23), new Double(78.23), (true)},
        {"James", new Integer(23), new Double(47.64), (false)},
        {"Hari", new Integer(23), new Double(78.23), (true)},
        {"James", new Integer(23), new Double(47.64), (false)}
    };
```

Please suggest something on this.

**

- Update 2

**

I observed that If we saw the pdf in 75% zoomin JTable looks accurate. But when this JTable is seen at 100% It is shown with a difference in borders and colors outside cells.
Do we have anything through which we can scale JTable printing i.e table.print(g) from 75 to 25% before printing it to pdf i.e 100%. If there are any JTable scaling ideas that would be great help!
Thanks!

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  3) No need to put a blank line on every other source code line! 4) I wonder why this glut of "can't put table into PDF" style questions all of a sudden?

Comment: ..& Hari, James & Sally? I [know them well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7369814/418556)!  ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using

```
table.setGridColor(Color.black);
```

Otherwise, if you want to use a custom renderer

```
table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,0));
```

(and make sure your renderer sets the border correctly).

**Edit**

Personally, your update smells like a new question (it would be really nice to see your new updated code - but it might be detrimental to the original question/answer).

I suspect your problem might lie somewhere in this (which seems a little fishy):

```
Border cellBorder = pTable.getBorder();
...
cellBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(cellBorder, 
            new ZoneBorder(iTop, iLeft, iBottom, iRight, Color.BLACK));
((JLabel) renderedComponent).setBorder(cellBorder);
```

Can you explain why you're grabbing the table's border, compounding it with another border, and then adding the result to every cell?

**Sidebar:** If you want additional help tagging the person in a comment to their answer makes them more likely to help than unaccepting their answer...