# Strikethrough and Underline doesn't appear on report pdf

Tags: java, swing, pdf, graphics, itext

I am working on a report application in which, I have to write some customizations on the pdf based on the JTable customization.

I am using:-
  iText 5.3.3.jar
  java jdk 1.6

Here I format a cell to print underline and strikethrough values. I code this in a cellrenderer.

To print these values on the pdf, I directly write JTable on the pdf. 
But as an output, I didn't get any underline/strikethrough.

[image: JTable image output]

[image: JTable pdf]

Since strikethrough and underline appears on the image. It doesn't appear on the pdf.

Following is the sample code to test it:-

**

- TableImage.java

**

```
package com.swing.data;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;



class TableImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Hari", new Integer(23), new Double(78.23), (true)},
            {"James", new Integer(23), new Double(47.64), (false)},
            {"Sally", new Integer(22), new Double(84.81), (true)}
        };
        String[] columns = {"Name", "Age", "GPA", "Pass"};
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
        JTableHeader h = table.getTableHeader();
        int x = table.getWidth();
        int y = table.getHeight();
        table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,0));
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ColumnAlignmentRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)));
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                x, y, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        table.paint(g2);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
        print(table);
    }
    private static void print(JTable table) {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        try { 
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("F://jTable.pdf")); 

            document.open(); 
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); 

            cb.saveState();

            PdfTemplate pdfTemplate = cb.createTemplate(table.getWidth(), table.getHeight());
            Graphics2D g2 = pdfTemplate.createGraphics(table.getWidth(), table.getHeight());

            table.print(g2);
            cb.addTemplate(pdfTemplate, 20, 100);
            g2.dispose();
            cb.restoreState();
            } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
            } 

        document.close();

      }


    private TableImage() {
    }
}
```

**

- ColumnAlignmentRenderer

**

```
package com.swing.data;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class ColumnAlignmentRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private TableCellRenderer mWrappedRenderer;
    private HashMap objFormatCellMap;

    public ColumnAlignmentRenderer(TableCellRenderer pWrappedRenderer) {
        mWrappedRenderer = pWrappedRenderer;
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable pTable,
            Object pValue, boolean pIsSelected, boolean pHasFocus, int pRow,
            int pColumn) {
        int hAlignment = SwingConstants.LEFT;
        int vAlignment = SwingConstants.CENTER;
        String pattern = "##000.0";
        Font font = pTable.getFont();
        Border cellBorder = pTable.getBorder();
        Map fontAttributes = font.getAttributes();
        fontAttributes.put(TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH,TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON);
        fontAttributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
        font = font.deriveFont(fontAttributes);
        // Border cellBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder();
        Color backgroundColor = Color.WHITE;
        Color foregroundColor = Color.BLACK;
        // Use the wrapped renderer
        Component renderedComponent = mWrappedRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(pTable, pValue, pIsSelected,
                        pHasFocus, pRow, pColumn);

        int iLeft = 1;
        int iRight = 1;
        int iTop = 1;
        int iBottom = 1;

        if (pRow == 0) {
            ((JLabel) renderedComponent).setFont(font);
        }
        if (pIsSelected) {
            renderedComponent.setBackground(pTable.getSelectionBackground());
        }
        return renderedComponent;
    }

    public void setHashFormatCellData(HashMap hashFormatCellData) {
        this.objFormatCellMap = hashFormatCellData;
    }

}
```

**

- Update 1:-

**
All your links are really helpful! But I got the correct image on JOPtionPane with the 
below code:-

```
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            x, y, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    table.paint(g2);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
```

From the above code table image comes with strikethrough and underline cells. But with the code resulting in pdf output, shows the cell contents without strikethrough and underline.

```
 PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); 
            cb.saveState();
            table.addNotify();
            table.doLayout();
            PdfTemplate pdfTemplate = cb.createTemplate(table.getWidth(), table.getHeight());
            Graphics2D g2 = pdfTemplate.createGraphics(table.getWidth(), table.getHeight());
            table.printAll(g2);
            cb.addTemplate(pdfTemplate, 20, 100);
            g2.dispose();
            cb.restoreState();
```

Please take a look at above and suggest something.

Answer (score 2):

remove follows 3. code lines, because to create an snapshot that will be expire on first event from Container or JComponents that required for repaint() (implemented in API)

```
Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
table.paint(g2);
```

see [Printing tutoria](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html)l especially [Printing Support in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/swing.html), tutorials contains runnable code examples,

quite common issue with [JTableHeader and BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369814/why-does-the-jtable-header-not-appear-in-the-image) by @Andrew Thompson