# create pdf file from JTable in Java

Tags: java, swing, pdf, jtable, jframe

I have a jframe with jtable, Button, and Jlabel. I have a problem When I click the button it appears that saved to pdf just fill in the table, but no column name.
And what if I also want to add jlabel into pdf file??

It's the script :

```
Private void print(){ 

Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());

try {
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:/jTable.pdf"));

  document.open();
  PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

  cb.saveState();
  Graphics2D g2 = cb.createGraphicsShapes(500, 500);

  Shape oldClip = g2.getClip();
  g2.clipRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

  table_pdf.print(g2);
  g2.setClip(oldClip);

  g2.dispose();
  cb.restoreState();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
document.close();}
```

it's screenshoot
[image]

and it's file pdf
[image]

Comment: `Private void print () {`  That would not compile and therefore cannot be the code used.  But for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If you are drawing a table you really should use PdfPTable. http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html

Comment: @scrappedcola  Good call.  With the difficulties of [getting a graphic from a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369814/why-does-the-jtable-header-not-appear-in-the-image) correctly, it is nice to know there is a specific class in the API that handles the details of creating a PDF conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Table's columns headers are shown as column header of the `JScrollPane` where the table is added. Try to use the method of `JScrollPane`

```
public JViewport getColumnHeader()
```

and print it above the table

Comment: @user1815938 or get JTableHeader from JTable (required BorderLayout for Container) put to the NORTH area