# when Jbutton is clicked either button is move or label text is changed. I just want to perform both

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, grid-layout

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JavaGUI extends JPanel {

    private Control control = new Control();
    private Keys keys = new Keys("Original starting value.");

    public JavaGUI() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        this.add(keys);
        this.add(control);

        private class Control extends JPanel {

            public Control() {
                this.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Update") {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Command: " + e.getActionCommand());
                        keys.string = String.valueOf(System.nanoTime());
                        //keys.label.setText(keys.string);  //remove comments cause button move
                        JButton j = (JButton) e.getSource();
                        j.setLocation(j.getX() + 10, j.getY() + 10);
                    }
                }));
            }
        }


        private class Keys extends JPanel {

            private String string;
            private JLabel label = new JLabel();

            public Keys(String s) {
                this.string = s;
                label.setText(s);
                this.add(label);
            }
        }


        private void display() {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("JavaGUI");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.add(this);
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new JavaGUI().display();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice, what should we do with this bad formatted code without any specific request with exception of a cryptic question title? Print it and stick it on a wall?

Comment: But how do i format this code dear. i cant understand. Isn't it good.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a GridLayout so you can't just move components around randomly. I suggest you read the Swing tutorial on [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for an understanding of how layout management works.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7375655/679982) will you please edit it so that I can remove the downvote, and then you remove your edit and I can upvote it (that's what I wanted to do in the first place >( ). I tried to dummy edit it myself but it got rejected

Answer (score 2):

I'll give all. The error was, that you set the String `string`, not the JLabel `label`.

Such behaviour, of something not having a GUI effect, could also have been caused by a missing `invokeLater` in `actionPerformed`.

You made classes for the used objects to set specific properties. That is a burocratic waste, hence I have rewritten it a bit.

If you resize the window, you'll see that the GridLayout manager again layouts, so that the JButton appears at its original position. You can use absolute positionwing with `setLayout(null)` using individual `setLocation`s.

```
public class JavaGUI extends JPanel {

    private JPanel control;
    private JLabel keys;

    public JavaGUI() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        keys = new JLabel("Original starting value.");
        keys.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(keys);

        control = new JPanel();
        control.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        control.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        control.setLayout(null);
        JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Update") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Command: " + e.getActionCommand());
                keys.setText(String.valueOf(System.nanoTime()));
                //keys.label.setText(keys.string);  //remove comments cause button move
                JButton j = (JButton) e.getSource();
                j.setLocation(j.getX() + 10, j.getY() + 10);
            }
        });
        button.setBounds(10, 10, 90, 24);
        control.add(button);
        add(control);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("JavaGUI");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JavaGUI());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

P.S. I have seen considerably worse code. This is actually neat code with only the superfluous classes.

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work also.  Now time ischanging bt button is not moving dude.

Comment: Also with invokeLater inside actionPerformed? Under Linux the code works as given. LookAndFeel dependent maybe.

Comment: But in my lapy it doesn't work. so what should I do. its imp 4 me to do this

Comment: Sorry for that; I have rewritten `public JavaGUI() {...}`.