# Headless painting

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I would like to paint a JPanel into a BufferedImage in headless mode (no GUI on the screen at all).

```
final JPanel panel = createPanel();
panel.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
panel.validate();

//  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
//  frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
//  frame.pack();
//  frame.setVisible(true);

final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
            panel.getBounds().width, 
            panel.getBounds().height, 
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
);

final Graphics2D gc = image.createGraphics();
gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

try {
    panel.paint(gc);
    ...save the image somewhere...
} finally {
    gc.dispose();
}
```

But I always get empty image until I put the panel into a heavy-weight component and show it on the screen (see the commented code). I don't want to show it, this application runs on server.

Here is SSCCE:

```
    public class Example {

    private static JPanel createPanel() {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());           
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Yeah, it's working!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));           
        final GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        panel.add(label, constraints);          
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JPanel panel = createPanel();
                panel.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
                panel.validate();

    //              JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    //              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //              frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    //              frame.pack();
    //              frame.setVisible(true);

                final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
                        panel.getBounds().width, 
                        panel.getBounds().height, 
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
                );    
                final Graphics2D gc = image.createGraphics();
                gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);    
                try {
                    panel.paint(gc);
                    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("image.png"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    gc.dispose();
                }                   
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Comment: The traditional way to do this under Linux is to run a "fake" X-window provider that doesn't actually display anything. But it does keep Java happy.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: See [Why does the JTable header not appear in the image?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7369814/418556) for tips on painting unrealized components.  If you cannot get it to work based on that, follow the advice of @GuillaumePolet & post an SSCCE.

Comment: The problem is that your label has a zero-size. See my edited answer with a simple fix (call `doLayout` instead of `validate()`). See also camickr answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components have a zero size until the component has been realized so the painting methods don't work.

Check out [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/). It will handle this problem for you by invoking doLayout() on the panel to make sure all components have a valid size.

Comment: My mistake, it is a zero-size issue but on its sub-components. Your answer is absolutely correct: +1

Comment: Yes, that works. I'm wondering why I have to call recursively doLayout() on my own. This should be done by simply validating the component. IMHO, another Swing's pitfall.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a snippet that paints a simple label to an image file and then the image file is opened (if on a Desktop computer).

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello world");
        label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        label.paint(image.getGraphics());
        File output = new File("C:\\test\\hello world.png");
        if (!output.getParentFile().exists()) {
            output.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(output);
    }

}
```

---

EDIT (with your SSCCE):

Don't call `validate()` but rather `doLayout()` on your panel (if you have nested panels, make sure to call it recursively):

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Example {

    private static JLabel label;

    private static JPanel createPanel() {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Yeah, it's working!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));

        final GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        panel.add(label, constraints);

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JPanel panel = createPanel();
                panel.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
                panel.doLayout();
                System.err.println(label.getSize() + "");
                // JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                // frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                // frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                // frame.pack();
                // frame.setVisible(true);

                final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(panel.getBounds().width, panel.getBounds().height,
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

                final Graphics2D gc = image.createGraphics();
                gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                try {
                    panel.paint(gc);
                    File output = new File("image.png");
                    ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(output);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    gc.dispose();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Again, doLayout() only works if you don't have nested panels. `ScreenImage` does doLayout() recursively to make sure all components on all panels have a size.

Comment: @camickr Yes indeed, this needs to be done recursively. I did follow your link and read the code of `ScreenImage`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `addNotify` on the root component you are attempting to print/paint will also solve the problem. The crux of the issue seems to be that validation calls short circuit unless the container has a 'peer'. Calling `addNotify` initializes the peer which allows subsequent calls to `Component.validate` to function as they normally would in a non-headless scenario.

Submitting this as an alternate solution because calling `doLayout` won't work in cases where components are more deeply nested due to `doLayout` not laying out subcomponents. (Although the ScreenImage class mentioned in camickr's answer addresses this by invoking doLayout recursively.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to instantiate the `BufferedImage` with one of it's constructor instead. `GraphicsEnvironment` class probably has to be used with a real GraphicsEnvironment (screen, ...)

```
new  BufferedImage(panel.getBounds().width, panel.getBounds().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB )
```

Comment: `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()` throws an exception in headless mode

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Yes, but I guess that @Behnil is testing on a computer with a `LocalGraphicsEnvironment` but that may generating incorrect image if there's not GUI (i.e. a `JFrame`).

Comment: It means that even though he has a "real" GE, his code is not working. Eventually, this will not work at all on a headless environment. So the problem does not come from there directly (although I agree that eventually it won't work).