# Painting JPanel to printable when it's not on screen

Tags: java, swing, printing, paint

I am using JPanels to simulate a print preview and just printing the content panel, however I have ran into a problem whereby if I try to print multiple panels that are essentially the same document, only the the one currently being displayed on screen will print.

Is there a way I can force the JPanel to repaint even if it is not currently on screen?

I have tried:

- Disabling double buffering via:

  - `JComponent.setDoubleBuffered()`
  - `RepaintManager.setDoubleBufferingEnabled()`
- Painting Twice
- Painting through `paint()`
- Painting through `repaint()`
- Painting through `print()`

Comment: Try `doLayout()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7369814/230513).

Comment: @trashgod Tried it, no luck.

Comment: [some musings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7372045/203657)

Comment: Have you tried [SwingUtilities.paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics,%20java.awt.Component,%20java.awt.Container,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)?

Comment: @VGR I was just messing about with that. I don't know whether I'm using it wrong but it stopped all pages from being painted.

Comment: @kleopatra I have looked into your linked thread and I now understand the component has to be "displayable" before it will be painted. I did the methods described but got no luck even though the component **is** saying it's displayable, I'll add code to my main post shortly.

Comment: Okay, now I am truly confused. I was putting together an SSCCE and that works perfectly and I cannot see the disparities between the SSCCE and the erroneous code. :S

Comment: I have worked out the discrepency. The components not wanting to print are actually `java.awt.Container`s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it to paint off screen and I felt like I was wasting my time battling the Swing API so I just cheated and made the panels display on screen as they are being printed; now I have a new "feature" that shows you the page being printed.

I'll leave the question open incase someone knows how to do this as I would prefer not to shove all the pages in the user's face.

---

**Update**

Turns out the problem was with components that had extended `java.awt.Container`, the Swing components must override certain AWT methods that deal with this sort of rendering.